# why function expression has been used when we could've used simple return statement

Tags: javascript

While I learn javascript, I;m very confused about using function expression. I understand the grammar syntax of it but just not sure the purpose of this. 
For example here

```
return function(){ alert("Quick! You've got a Fast Pass to " + pass + "!");};
```

can't we just use return and then the statement. I'll post where this code is from

```
var parkRides = [["Birch Bumpers", 40], ["Pines Plunge", 55],
                ["Cedar Coaster", 20], ["Ferris Wheel of Firs", 90]];

var fastPassQueue = ["Cedar Coaster", "Pines Plunge", "Birch Bumpers", "Pines Plunge"];
var wantsRide = "British Bumpers";
function buildTickets(allRides, passRides, pick) {
  if(passRides[0] == pick) {
    var pass = passRides.shift();
    return function(){ alert("Quick! You've got a Fast Pass to " + pass + "!");};
  } else {
    for(var i = 0; i < allRides.length; i++){
      if(allRides[i][0] == pick){
        return function() { alert("A ticket is printing for " + pick + "!\n" + "Your wait time is about " + allRides[i][1] + "minutes. ");};
      }
    }
  }
}
var ticket = buildTickets(parkRides,fastPassQueue, wantsRide)();
tickets();
```

I mean we can still use the variable pass since it's in the same function even without new function(). why do we need to use closure as well here?

Comment: For this specific example, it's because you want to return a function. Therefore this question is similar to asking "Why return a number when we can just return a string"? Because we want to use a number. As for why the code wants a function you need to look at the logic of the code. Maybe the author wants a flexible way to handle the messages. So instead of returning a string we can return a function that can then decide to do what's necessary

Comment: I think you understand it well. What you presented here is just redundant code. It could have been written in many different ways.

Comment: Related (Not a duplicate) where they return it to a promise https://stackoverflow.com/q/39680799/125981  I would then wonder "Is it called anywhere else?"

Comment: this seems overly complicated.. in this specific example, since you're immediately calling the returned function, it's senseless to return a function. you might as well simplify it and just call the alert. there are good use-cases for returning a function but this is not one of them.

Comment: Question is there a typo perhaps meant as `var wantsRide = "Birch Bumpers";` in there?  `British Bumpers` will give an error here I think.  Also `tickets();` does not exist, was it meant as `ticket();`?

Comment: Note that if you  do `console.log(ticket);` at the end, it will log `undefined` in this context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes you want control exactly when to run certain logic (in above case `alert`) by returning a `function` you can then control when you can `alert` by calling `tickets`

Imagine if user has set a preference to not see `alert` messages, the logic would be as simple as: `isAlertAllowed ? tickets() : null`